# How to get percentage of result set for each day?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve the percentage of available products at specific merchants over the last 30 days.

Desired result example:

```
20210504 merchant1 20%
20210504 merchant2 30%
20210505 merchant1 25%
20210505 merchant2 35%
```

There are 3 tables:

1. availability (containing availability info for each product and merchant and day)
2. products (where the manufacturer_id is, that we want to filter for)
3. merchants (merchant info)

Minimal example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wtnK5R4DWi7Dy6LwLaP4mX/0

This returns the percentage for only one merchant and one day:

```
-- get percentage of available products per merchant over time
SELECT
   m.name AS metric,
   t.s AS AMOUNT_AVAILABLE,
   count(*) AS AMOUNT_TOTAL,
   t.s / count(*) AS percentage
FROM availability p
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT count(*) AS s FROM availability p2
    INNER JOIN products mp on p2.SKU = mp.SKU
    WHERE
            availability = 'sofort lieferbar'
        AND date = curdate() - interval 1 day -- testing for one day, but we want a time series
        AND mp.MANUFACTURER_ID = 1
        -- AND p2.merchant_id = p.merchant_id -- does not work
        -- AND merchant_id = 2
        -- GROUP BY merchant_id
    )  t
INNER JOIN products mp on p.SKU = mp.SKU
INNER JOIN merchants m ON m.id = p.MERCHANT_ID

WHERE
        p.date = curdate() - interval 1 day 
    and mp.MANUFACTURER_ID = 1
    -- and merchant_id = 2
GROUP BY
    merchant_id
```

Now I am trying to somehow merge the cross join with the from table so I get the info for each merchant and day. How can a cross join be joined with the from table?

Data & Shema:

```
create table merchants
(
    id           tinyint unsigned                                      not null
        primary key,
    name         varchar(255)                                          null
);
 INSERT INTO merchants (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Amazon');
 INSERT INTO merchants (id, name) VALUES (2, 'eBay');
 
 
 create table availability
(
    DATE         date                                                                                not null,
    SKU          char(10)                                                                            not null,
    merchant_id  tinyint unsigned                                                                    not null,
    availability enum ('sofort lieferbar', 'verzögert lieferbar', 'nicht lieferbar', 'außer Handel') null,
    constraint DATE
        unique (DATE, SKU, merchant_id)
);

INSERT INTO test.availability (DATE, SKU, merchant_id, availability) VALUES ('2021-05-11', '1', 1, 'sofort lieferbar');
INSERT INTO test.availability (DATE, SKU, merchant_id, availability) VALUES ('2021-05-11', '1', 2, 'nicht lieferbar');
INSERT INTO test.availability (DATE, SKU, merchant_id, availability) VALUES ('2021-05-12', '1', 1, 'sofort lieferbar');
INSERT INTO test.availability (DATE, SKU, merchant_id, availability) VALUES ('2021-05-12', '1', 2, 'nicht lieferbar');
INSERT INTO test.availability (DATE, SKU, merchant_id, availability) VALUES ('2021-05-13', '1', 1, 'nicht lieferbar');
INSERT INTO test.availability (DATE, SKU, merchant_id, availability) VALUES ('2021-05-13', '1', 2, 'sofort lieferbar');


create table products
(
    SKU               char(8)                                      not null
        primary key,
    NAME              varchar(255)                                 null,
    MANUFACTURER_ID   mediumint unsigned                           null,
    updated           datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP           not null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO test.products (SKU, NAME, MANUFACTURER_ID, updated) VALUES ('1', 'Sneaker', 1, '2021-05-12 02:27:46');
INSERT INTO test.products (SKU, NAME, MANUFACTURER_ID, updated) VALUES ('2', 'Ball', 1, '2021-05-12 02:27:46');
INSERT INTO test.products (SKU, NAME, MANUFACTURER_ID, updated) VALUES ('3', 'Pen', 2, '2021-05-12 02:27:46');
INSERT INTO test.products (SKU, NAME, MANUFACTURER_ID, updated) VALUES ('4', 'Paper', 2, '2021-05-12 02:27:46');
```

Comment: Can you provide create statements for your tables? And some sample data?

Comment: @E.Aigle I just provided an example and fiddle. Hope this makes it more clear what I am trying to acchieve.

Comment: @merlin There is only one value per merchant per day in your example. Does that mean you are trying to get the average over the range? Because the average over the day would just be 0 or a 100 otherwise depending on if it was available or not that day. If you are trying to get the average over the range, I'm not sure I understand what the dates in your desired output are..... Maybe I'm totally missing something that's super clear but it's got me stumped.

Comment: @merlin or is it the average of all the products available that day, that are from either merchant?

Comment: @E.Aigle Looks like I have "oversimplified" it. You are right, there are several values per merchant and day. I want to get the average percantage of available products per day and merchant. In other words I want to know if at e.g. amazon my products are available per day. Idealy 100%, but sometimes it is only 2 of 3 products. e.g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a query which seems to work for the data you have provided. Let me know if there's any issue and I'll see what I can do.

```
SELECT CONCAT('merchant', t.ID) as merchant,
       t.Date,
       g.prod_available / t.all_prod_from_merch AS percentage_available 
       # gets total number of products in time range Date,
FROM      (SELECT ID,
                  COUNT(merchant_ID) AS all_prod_from_merch 
           FROM merchants m 
           JOIN availability a 
             ON m.ID = a.merchant_ID 
           WHERE Date < CURDATE() 
             AND Date >= curdate() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
           GROUP BY merchant_ID,
                    Date                 ) t 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT merchant_ID,
                  Date,
                  COUNT(merchant_ID) AS prod_available 
           FROM availability 
           WHERE AVAILABILITY = 'sofort lieferbar' 
             AND date IN (SELECT Date 
                          FROM availability 
                          WHERE date < CURDATE() 
                            AND date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY 
                          GROUP BY Date                )
           GROUP BY merchant_ID,
                    Date                   ) g 
       ON g.merchant_ID = t.ID 
      AND g.Date = t.Date 
ORDER BY t.date;
```

The first select in the join gets the total number of products in the time range for each merchant. The second one gets those available from each merchant. So the select at the beginning just does the fraction.

Comment: thank you, your answer has led me to the right directiion.